# HTC explorer A310e - does it have magnetic sensor?

Tags: htc-explorer, compass

I want to use any compass app to my HTC explorer A310e model. But i am not sure whether it will work or not? Is it something related to hardware support to have magnetic sensor? And is there any way to activate it so that i can use that app in my phone?

Comment: Downvoting because I found the answer by googling *htc explorer compass*.

Answer (score 1):

[GSMArena's listing for the HTC Explorer](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_explorer-4102.php) doesn't indicate a compass, and [this post on an HTC Forum](http://www.htcforums.com/explorer/10153-sky-map-app-compass-issue.html) concurs. Without a compass in the device, compass apps obviously won't work.